# device is not compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play

yesterday i had uploaded app in Google play store but when i tried to download this app from store it says that device is not compatible with this version for all devices and also when i tried to search this app from play store it not searchable but when i searched from web it is displaying if any know why this problem are coming please help me thanks in advance here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    package="com.nopaltechnologies.resume"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"    
            android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>
</manifest>
```

Comment: is this your entire manifest file?, can't see application tag-

Comment: i did not paste application tag here which is necessary i pasted

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: Device is not compatible:

**Reason**: The device you want to install your app on might be version below Android 2.3.2.

**Problem**: Not searchable on the device but searchable on the web:

**Reason**: The apps not compatible with your device would not show up in your device play store but would show up on play.google.com

Comment: as i mentioned it showing for all devices by the way i am using above than 2.3.3

Comment: another reason for the app not showing up in your appstore could be a conflict between your device resolution and application resolution or some apps are set for specific region only.